# Typescript file path .ts inside code, not correct when compiled

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, ts-node

I'm using the following code inside `workers.ts`, to load a Bull MQ worker file.

```
const worker = new Worker('parse', `${ __dirname }/workers/worker-parse.ts`);
```

Now during development I use the following script, which is working fine

```
npx pm2 start src/index.ts --watch
```

But when I build using tsc, the .ts file path won't work anymore since it's compiled to .js.

This is my production script

```
"prod": "tsc && npx pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production",
```

Now I'm wondering, is there any way that I can make sure that in the compiled version, my workers script will look for worker-parse.js, instead of .ts.

Or is there any way in TS to omit the extension? (Tried it but doesn't work out of the box)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using `worker-parse.js` in *typescript*. In JS that would be obviously correct. Depending on the used resolver(or runtime) that could work in TS. E.g. with `nodenext` resolutions having `.js` extension for ts file imports is regiured, but no idea if that works with workers for your exact case.
2. Get the extension of current file from `import.meta.url` (or `__filename`)

```
const ext = import.meta.url.split('.').pop()!;
const worker = new Worker('parse', `${ __dirname }/workers/worker-parse.${ext}`);
```

Comment: Good point Dimava, although it feels like using 2 is a bit hacky, I did get it working now, I'm using tsc-watch instead of nodemon, it's faster and feels reads the .js by default. for production I'm using tsc to build and pm2 to run

Comment: @MiguelStevens I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx which can import anything from anything, so '.js' import would work there as is I guess (I had to #2, but I did use Piscina workers)